# ScriptableObject List to Json

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was wondering what is the best way to save a list of ScriptableObjects to Json. I'm currently using Newtonsoft.Json way of doing it and is giving me a warning since the way of loading data from the Json is creating instances of the scriptableObjects with "new ScriptObject" instead of "ScriptableObject.CreateInstance" method. It's just a warning and I don't see any major errors, still, it's picking my interest.

Thanks.

Comment: Though it's a bit older I used [JSONObject](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/JSONObject)

Comment: `loading data from the Json is creating instances of the scriptableObjects` ... So is your question about `ScriptableObject List to Json` as in the title or the other way round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely suggest using the Newtonsoft version ([JsonDotNet](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json))
Had so much problem with the Unity version. Things got so much easier when i switched to Newtonsoft version.

You can simply say to serialize

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

or you can simply deserialize by doing this

```
MyClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use JsonUtility. JsonUtility is a unity class with utility functions for working with JSON data.

You can use FromJsonOverwrite(string json, object objectToOverwrite) for ScriptableObjects and MonoBehaviours.

You should not use new keyword to create or instantiate scriptableObjects and monoBehaviours. So JsonUtility is more suitable than other standard .net json library like Newtonsoft for monoBehaviours and scriptableObjects.

[JsonUtility Unity3D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html)

Comment: Or if you want some additional customization, I recommend [JsonDotNet](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347). You'll have to write converters for Unity objects (or it'll try and serialize EVERYTHING and will fail to deserialize because of readonly properties), but it's great when you need that extra power.

Comment: I had problems with the JsonUtility like Lists losing its contents, the way I have things is probably making it hard for that library. I'm sticking to Newtonsoft since I haven't found errors so far.

Comment: You need to add list to a class as a field. Use [SerializeField] for fields and [System.Serializeable] for classes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe its wrong approach, but for my goals i wrote my own Serialization/Deserialization of Scriptable objects list to json, coz i store all my player data (player position, inventory, quests) on server in single text field for save/load simplicity. Moreover, i use WebGL build, so i dont know how Newtonsoft will behave on different platforms. And i dont want to test this as well)

```
private string SerializeSOList<T>(List<T> SO_List)
    {
        string result = "";
        foreach (T item in SO_List)
        {
            result += JsonUtility.ToJson(item) + ", ";
        }
        return result;
    }

    private List<T> DeserializeSOList<T> (string json_string)
    {
        string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "}," };
        List<T> result = new List<T>();
        string[] splitted = json_string.Split(stringSeparators, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
        for(int i =0; i < splitted.Length-1; i++)
        {
            string SO_string = splitted[i] + "}";
            Debug.Log(SO_string);
            T itemBasic = (T)System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(SO_string, itemBasic);
            result.Add(itemBasic);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

then you just call this functions for any Scriptable object as follow :

```
[SerializeField] public List<ItemBasic> basicUpgrades = new List<ItemBasic>();

    string json_basicUpgrades = SerializeSOList(basicUpgrades);

    basicUpgrades = DeserializeSOList<ItemBasic>(json_basicUpgrades);
```